# HTML / Javascript callback not executing

Tags: javascript

The HTML form shows but the javascript callback is not executing.
(and how do I combine into one file?)

thx

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Mouse click test</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Mouse Click Test</h1>
<p>Click the mouse on the test link below. A message below will indicate which button was clicked.</p>
<h2><a href = "#" id = "testlink">Test Link</a></h2>
<form name = "form1">
<textarea rows = "10" cols = "70" name = "info"></textarea>
</form>
<script  type = "text/javascript" scr = "click.js">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
function mousestatus(e){
    document.write("hello");
    if (!e) e = window.event;
    btn = e.button;
    whichone = (btn < 2) ? "Left" : "Right";
    message = e.type + " : " + whichone + "\n";
    document.form1.info.value += message;
}  
obj = document.getElementById("testlink");
obj.onmousedown = mousestatus;
obj.onmouseup = mousestatus;
obj.onclick = mousestatus;
obj.ondblclick = mousestatus;
```

Comment: Remove `document.write("hello");` from the function.

Comment: If the js is in click.js, then the script tag has a typo for src attribute. Change `<script  type = "text/javascript" scr = "click.js">` to `<script  type = "text/javascript" src="click.js">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attribute for the `<script>` tag is `src`, not `scr`. This:

```
<script  type = "text/javascript" scr = "click.js">
```

Should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="click.js">
```

And get rid of the `document.write` call, [`document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Document.write) will:

> Writing to a document that has already loaded without calling `document.open()` will automatically perform a `document.open` call.

And [`document.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.open):

> If a document exists in the target, this method clears it.

So calling `document.write` anywhere except inside an inline `<script>` will erase everything before inserting your new stuff; about the only time you should use `document.write` is in things like this:

```
<p>Where is <script type="text/javascript">document.write('pancakes')</script> house?</p>
```

You'd usually use `console.log('...')` or `console.debug('...')` for quick debug messages (assuming that you're using a browser with a console and you have the console open).

Once you take care of those issues, you should have something that does more interesting things than throw errors (or nothing at all): http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/5kHVy/

You might want to read up the newer event handling interfaces (such as [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener)).

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be src="click.js"?

```
<script  type = "text/javascript" scr = "click.js">
                                  ^^^
```